# Run MS SQL Server Express on Linux Mint

Tags: sql, linux-mint

I am aware that MS SQL Server 2016 is compatible with Linux. Despite this flavor of SQL, I am needing to run SQL Express for training purposes.  Is there a method to successfully operate Microsoft SQL Server Express in the Linux Mint environment?

Comment: sql server on linux is not live yet,it may be ready by 2017

Comment: is it possible ? did you figure it out ? I am also looking to do the same

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an interesting question and shouldn't be marked down. After searching online, i came up with his tutorial on setting up mssql server on linux. I tested on linux mint 18.1.

http://www.tecmint.com/install-ms-sql-server-centos-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 1):

I installed MSSQL 2016 on Ubuntu last night. Mint is Debian based so it 'might' work. The instructions are here ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu

The installation process is very simple - in fact it literally took seconds, since it uses the familiar `apt-get install` package manager install which is available with Mint. One thing to be aware of is the requirement for `openssl` needs version `1.0.2` - this caught me out. I tinkered around trying to upgrade to the correct version on my ubuntu server and did have the correct version installed but MSSQL still would not install. So I created a `16.04` version of ubuntu and then it installed easily. I'm not sure if my comments qualify as an 'answer' but I'd just try and install it as if you have the dependencies I would think you'll be okay.